# How can I display detailed network timing information in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This screenshot in the [Chrome Developer Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing) shows very detailed information on what takes how long to fulfill a HTTP request:

[image]

When I look that information up on Chrome 37 I only see a summary of this information:

[image]

Is there any way to enabled this detailed view? Or is the screenshot from the documentation just from an older version of Chrome and the level of detail was reduced in newer versions?

It would be really helpful to track down why my requests take this long before they are even sent to the server.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? I am experiencing the same problem on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 on Windows 7 x64. 

On the documentation page, one of the screenshots shows a cursor that appears to be from **KDE on Linux**. Maybe the feature is OS-dependent. Just a guess.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, because I have seen that at least *sometimes* the SSL details appear. So the feature is there, but not always appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at this in years, but checked the current state of this. As of now (Version 75) of Chrome the panel from the DevTools looks nearly exactly like the screenshot of the documentation back then:

[image]

It's most probably impossible to retrace this now, but I assume that the screenshot in the documentation was from a newer version (either a developer version or a preview) back then.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome probably does not re-establish a TCP/SSL connection with a server for each request. It holds on and reuses existing connections. If you have recently connected to the server over SSL, the browser will reuse that connection instead of creating a new one per HTTP request.

(TCP operates at a lower level than HTTP, and so it is possible for multiple HTTP connections to use the same TCP connection.)

So basically, the SSL details do not appear in the Network timing chart because there is no SSL initialization going on for that particular request.

On windows 7, running `netstat -ano` will show you all active TCP connections.

Other parts of the timing breakdown may also be hidden, such as "DNS Lookup", if it does not happen for each request.

Comment: You only mention why the SSL details don't show up, but you may want to make it more explicit that this applies to the "DNS lookup" and "Initial connection" as well.